# Using PL/pgSQL conditionals without creating a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pg-promise

I would like to create a Postgres table and alter it, but only if it does not exist in the first place. I don't think this should be a function, as this is ran only once during the app startup. I tried to execute this code from [pg-promise nodejs lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise) using `client.none(sql, params)`, but it gave me an error `syntax error at or near "IF"`, so I'm guessing it has to be some other execution method, or my SQL is fundamentally flawed. Thanks!

```
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = $1 AND table_name = $2
) THEN
    CREATE TABLE $2~ (zoom smallint, idx bigint, tile bytea, PRIMARY KEY (zoom, idx));
    ALTER TABLE $2~ ALTER COLUMN tile SET STORAGE EXTERNAL;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: [anonymous code block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-do.html)

Comment: @Abelisto, that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!!! Could you make into an answer and I will resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost there

```
do $$
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = $1 AND table_name = $2
) THEN
CREATE TABLE $2~ (zoom smallint, idx bigint, tile bytea, PRIMARY KEY (zoom, idx));
ALTER TABLE $2~ ALTER COLUMN tile SET STORAGE EXTERNAL;
END IF;
END $$;
```